# jQuery this.data-x not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a table containing the periodic table, and this jQuery to, when you click on an element's name, tell you what it's full name is.

However when I click on one nothing happens... I've tried different syntax etc but still nothing.

Here's what my table HTML looks like (class="s-4" means font-size:4; - doesn't mean anything to this question):

```
<td class="s-4"><a class="e" href="#" data-e="B">B</a></td>
<td class="s-4"><a class="e" href="#" data-e="C">C</a></td>
<td class="s-4"><a class="e" href="#" data-e="N">N</a></td>
<td class="s-4"><a class="e" href="#" data-e="O">O</a></td>
<td class="s-4"><a class="e" href="#" data-e="F">F</a></td>
<td class="s-4"><a class="e" href="#" data-e="Ne">Ne</a></td>
```

And here's what my jQuery/JavaScript looks like:

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".e").click(function() {
    var e = this.data-e;
      if(e == 'H') { $("#a").html('H is Hydrogen'); }
      if(e == 'He') { $("#a").html('He is Helium'); }
      if(e == 'Li') { $("#a").html('Li is Lithium'); }
      if(e == 'Be') { $("#a").html('Be is Beryllium'); }
      if(e == 'B') { $("#a").html('B is Boron'); }
      if(e == 'C') { $("#a").html('C is Carbon'); }
      if(e == 'N') { $("#a").html('N is Nitrogen'); }
etc etc... and then

    });
    });
    </script>
```

#a refers to the <h1> at the top of my page, and .e refers to the links (that you click on to find out the element's name)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var e = this.data-e
```

should be

```
var e = $(this).data('e');
```

or

```
var e = $(this).attr('data-e');
```

Read about **[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)**

Comment: You would probably see this by looking at the JavaScript console in your web browser.  Generally, when JavaScript "does nothing", that's the first place I look.

Comment: Amazing how simple that was. Thanks

Comment: @thecodeparadox I tried, it said wait 12 minutes. Will do soon.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute data-e that you want to access has wrong syntax in your code.

Wrong syntax

```
var e = this.data-e;
```

Correct syntax

```
var e =  $(this).attr(data-e);
```

Your code will be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".e").click(function() {
var e = $(this).attr(data-e);
    if(e == 'H') { $("#a").html('H is Hydrogen'); }
  if(e == 'He') { $("#a").html('He is Helium'); }
  if(e == 'Li') { $("#a").html('Li is Lithium'); }
  if(e == 'Be') { $("#a").html('Be is Beryllium'); }
  if(e == 'B') { $("#a").html('B is Boron'); }
  if(e == 'C') { $("#a").html('C is Carbon'); }
  if(e == 'N') { $("#a").html('N is Nitrogen'); }
etc etc... and then

});
});
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't give the HTML for that. I do also have a &lt;h1 id="a"&rt;&lt;h1&rt; at the top. Anyway it's all working now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = this.data-e
```

should be

```
var e = $(this).attr(data-e);
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
var e = this.data-e
```

with this one

```
var e = $(this).attr("data-e");
```